# Why does Firebug freeze Firefox while running a GWT project?

Tags: firefox, gwt, firebug, gwt-bootstrap

I am using Firefox 31, GWT 2.7, GWT Bootstrap 2 and run with super dev mode. Sometimes I click on some widgets and my browser freezes and Firebug's *Script* panel shows the following:

[image: Firebug's Script panel freezing browser]

I would like to know why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Try turning Firebug off for your application page. Will the execution still stop at 'debugger'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug stops the JavaScript execution automatically on the [`debugger` keyword](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Debugging#debugger.3B_keyword). You can continue the script execution by clicking the continue button (the button with the blue triagle within the panel toolbar) or by hitting <kbd>F8</kbd> or you just reload the page.

To avoid that you have the following options:

1. Remove the `debugger` keyword(s) from the code
2. Clicking the *Disable* button as suggested in the notification
3. Deactivate the [*Script* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel) (by right-clicking the panel tab and clicking *Enabled* in the popup menu to uncheck it)
4. Deactivate Firebug for the current website (by clicking the stand-by button in the upper right corner or hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>)
5. Deactivate Firebug within the Add-ons Manager (available via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

Comment: This also happend in chrome browser too . My chrome browser hasn't firebug plugin. If my project was deployed , am I declare to users as you described ? (1) I am using gwt and `debugger` keywords not contain in my code (2) After clicked on **Disable** button , my browser was freeze. But thanks for your useful facts.

Comment: You have to continue the script execution or reload the page to unfreeze it. If your code does not contain `debugger` keywords, you need to check where they come from and remove them there or download a release version of the third-party code you use. (The file name is displayed within the *Script* panel toolbar. Unfortunately your screenshot doesn't show it.) You don't have to tell your users about the `debugger` keyword, as that is only relevant for people using a DevTool like Firebug, (which normal site users don't do). Also, know that every DevTool has a debugger, also the one in Chrome.